# Webpack for backend: the request of a dependency is an expression

Tags: node.js, webpack, backend

Trying to follow [this tutorial](http://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-I) for using webpack for the backend I have successfully build the bundle, unfortunately on completion it warns`Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression`, I used `webpack-node-externals` module to externalize the whole `node_modules` directory but **I need** to dynamically require some modules from `node_modules` but webpack replaces my require with an error. Apparently [there's a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38697321/webpack-require-expression-external) to tell webpack to leave alone those requires that cannot resolve but it warns `webpack: Using compiler.parser is deprecated`, apparently that way of creating an inline plugin has been deprecated but I'm not able to translate that to the new syntax which should be:

```
compiler.plugin("compilation", function(compilation, params) {
  params.normalModuleFactory.plugin("parser", function(parser, parserOptions) {
    parser.plugin(/* ... */);
  });
});
```

According to [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/releases/tag/v2.1.0-beta.23). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
function IgnoreUnresolvedPlugin() { }

IgnoreUnresolvedPlugin.prototype.apply = function (compiler) {
  compiler.plugin("compilation", function (compilation, data) {
    data.normalModuleFactory.plugin("parser", function (parser) {
      parser.plugin('call require', function (params) {
        if (params.arguments.length !== 1) { return; }

        const param = this.evaluateExpression(params.arguments[0]);

        if (!param.isString() && !param.isConditional()) {
          return true;
        }
      });
    });
  });
};
```