# Circular references in Webpack build of kurento-client-js

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, kurento

I'm facing an error while trying to build kurento-client-js with Webpack 2 + babel.

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/kurento-client/lib/register.js
60:20-33 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

On execution it results in

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "."
```

I believe that the issue itself is сaused by `require` inside `/lib/register.js`

```
//kurento-clinet/lib/register.js
if (constructor == undefined)
    return register(require(name));
```

And the code that cause errors:

```
//kurento-clinet/lib/index.js
//this module requires kurento-client resulting in circular reference
register('kurento-client-core')
```

The kurento bower package contains distributive built with the browserify.

I wonder if anyone tried to build `kurento-client-js` using webpack. Please share your experience.

**EDIT**:

Circular dependency error stack trace:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'MediaObject' of undefined
at Object._typeof (KurentoClient.js:42)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 0d7eac46304670c5f3b5:19)
at Object._typeof (index.js:44)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 0d7eac46304670c5f3b5:19)
at Object.module.exports (HubPort.js:21)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 0d7eac46304670c5f3b5:19)
at Object._typeof (index.js:32)
at ...
```

Comment: Sounds like something worth filing a bug for. It should be there responsibility. It's absolutely possible to build a nice bundle that will build with Webpack and also work with Node, but it seems like they have done their own complex build process instead.

Comment: @loganfsmyth, absolutely agree. Since kurento team was acquired by Twilio, they stopped active project development. I thought about rewriting the whole client from the scratch, but decided against it after diving deeper into sources. Almost all files and packages were auto-generated by some IDL tool and they look like complete mess now. It will take more than a week to reassemble the client. Of course, it would be great, because a lot of legacy code will be eliminated. However, I'm looking for a simpler solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

First of all webpack complains about a dynamic dependency (which cannot be resolved when building the bundle). It's **not** a circular dependency.

I got it working like this:

1) in your app's `main.js` require manually all the modules which the `register()` function might need

```
require('kurento-client-core')
require('kurento-client-elements')
require('kurento-client-filters')

const kc = require('kurento-client-core/lib/index.js')

console.log(kc)
```

2) use this webpack plugin to completely ignore unresolved/dynamic `require()` calls

```
//in webpack.config.js
plugins:[

function() {
  this.parser.plugin('call require', function(expr) {
    if (expr.arguments.length !== 1) {
      return;
    }

    const param = this.evaluateExpression(expr.arguments[0]);
    if (!param.isString() && !param.isConditional()) {
      return true;
    }
  });
}
//... other plugins
]
```

Webpack2 will warn about old plugin format, but it does work

Credits go to:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42527120/646156

Comment: Circular references are in both `kurento-client` and `kurento-client-core` libs. `kurento-client-core` requires `HubPort`, which requires `kurento-client`, which requires `kurento-client-core`. I tried your code, webpack assembles the package but it just don't work in browser, fails on `var MediaObject = require('kurento-client-core').abstracts.MediaObject;` (in `kurento-client` module referenced by `kurento-client-core`).

Comment: I have  console.logged the kurento-client. It did work

Comment: The `kc` variable in your code sample is an instance of the `kurento-client-core` module, not the `kurento-client`. I'm using kurento-client v6.6.2. `require('kurento-client/lib/index.js')` throws an error.

Comment: To put it otherwise, I have a working bundle with the above setup

Comment: I really appreciate that you found time to answer my question, but it just doesn't work in my case. Maybe you are using another version of `kurento-client` module. I've attached an error to the original question to demonstrate circular dependency issue.

Comment: I get it now. Let me try that and get back to you